# How to test a registry key exists with a particular value without giving error messages

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where we need to check the registry key with a specific value and if it's not found create the key along with the value.I have tried the below code snippet but when I try to run it I get error message of "Cannot find the Registry test-path because it doesn't exist" when the registry file doesn't exist.

```bsh
$Camera = (Get-ItemProperty "Registry::HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" -Name "Getin")."Getin"

if((Get-ItemProperty "Registry::HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" -Name "Getin")."Getin" -eq 0){
    Write-Output "Registry hive exists"
} else {
    Write-Output "Registry hive doesn't exists"
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" -Name "Getin" -Value "0" -PropertyType "DWORD" -Force | Out-Null
}
```

How to overcome the situation without getting error messages.
As there are multiple registry check-in any solution on the problem?

Comment: please take a look at the `try/catch/finally` structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use the param `-ErrorAction`
Something like that should work:

```
if( -not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" -Name "Getin" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Getin))){
Write-Output "Registry hive exists"
} else {
    Write-Output "Registry hive doesn't exists"
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" -Name "Getin" -Value "0" -PropertyType "DWORD" -Force | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: when the registry hive doesn't exists, there is error I get along with output " Registry hive doesnt exists". The error is  New-Item Property : Cannot find path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" because it doesn't exist

Comment: @Hidei yes I know that, thats the reason why you add the parameter `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ` to the `Get-ItemProperty` command. Did you test my example?

Comment: I tested your example but still I am getting the error line even after adding -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue. Any solution to get rid of error line?

Comment: Are you sure that this path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" exists? otherwise you can not create a property...

Comment: The solution works. Initially there was no "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" registry hive. Once the key is created the solution works . Thank you

Comment: If the Getin value is 1 how can we check in the code snippet?

Comment: `(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Hello" -Name "Getin" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Getin) -eq 1`